# How can I get the right relative paths in my compiled LESS css files?

Tags: css, less

I'm having a problem with LESS breaking relative URLs in my compiled files. For example, I have;

```
├── style.less
├── style.css
├── assets
│   ├── img
│   │   └──  bg.png
│   ├── less
│   │   └──  included.less
```

Style.less imports included.less which has the following line;

```
body {background: url(../img/wall-texture.png);}
```

But the output in style.css becomes

```
body {background: url(assets/less/assets/less/../img/wall-texture.png);}
```

What's going on here, and how can I fix this so that my paths remain correct after compiling? I realize that perhaps my relative path in included.less needs to be adjusted, and that's fine, but currently, with how less is doubling "assets/less" it makes it extremely convoluted to get the right path while maintaining a reasonable folder structure. Besides that I'm using git submodules to include different LESS projects, so I don't really want to change either the code in the less files or the folder structure, I just want to coerce LESS into compiling correctly. (I've tried all of the Windows compilers I can find, and they all behave the same.)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is the reason I stopped using Less in favor of Sass.  If you're using a Windows GUI compiler like WinLESS or SimpLESS, the only thing you can really do is run a script over the generated CSS file to strip out undesirable path components.

Comment: I'm not opposed to using command line tools. I am very stuck on LESS though because I want to use Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: There are a couple Sass ports of Twitter Bootstrap out there.

Comment: LESS >> SASS, but this doesn't the is question. I use lessc in linux and never had any problem. Try use absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: Shankar, an absolute path doesn't really solve the problem for me, because I've got a copy running locally and copy on a server that both have different absolute paths.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem. However, everything looks fine. The relative paths are retained, i.e., my `style.css` defines still `body {background: url(../img/wall-texture.png);}`. So, please add some more information about your setup. Which less version? I used 1.3.0 for my tests.

Comment: Less version 1.3.0. WinLess version 1.5.3. @phammer What compiler are you using.

Comment: @JosiahSprague I use command line lessc in version 1.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/marklagendijk/WinLess/issues/12
It seems to be related with exactly the version you are using (1.5.3). I recommend to update to the latest winless build which is already 1.8.0.

There have been several issues with relative paths along the way of winless. But most of them seem to be fixed. See also https://github.com/marklagendijk/WinLess/issues/search?q=path

Please note that the default behavior of the less compiler is actual to retain the relative path as you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

There may well be a solution that resolves your compiling. If not, one possible solution (which *does* require you to change your LESS files) is to interpolate the path. That way, the compiler might leave it alone as far as appending to it:

```
body {background: url(~"../img/wall-texture.png");}
```

Comment: This is only partially a solution. The main problem with this approach is that the path has to be relative to the output path rather than the original LESS file, which is doable but extremely confusing both because the path has to be manually figured out by the original developer and because future developers will have to do a little bit of work to figure out what is going on. All of that is ok, but it tends to get confusing if any of the files are moved around in relation to one another.

Comment: @JosiahSprague: I agree it is only a partial solution. What output were you hoping for? Is it `/assets/img/wall-texture.png`?